# Создание поэтапной диагностики

Tags: php, html

дайте, пожалуйста, примеры, либо советы по созданию поэтапной диагностики.
Нужна простая и легкая.

Что имею ввиду:
А (а1, а2 (а21, а,22), а3), Б ( б1, б2).
Соответственно клиент выбирает А1, прокидывается информация + 3 варианта (а1, а2, а3) и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

связанные дропдауны.
Первый селект - данные выбираете сами в системе.
Все последующие - через ajax запрашиваете.

Так же, не забудьте, что если у вас например 4 шага, и вы поменяли второй, то обнулите все за ним последующие